# Objective - C, what does [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width actually give and what does initWithSize: actually require?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a GUI, with a main menu, a second screen and a back button to the main menu. From the initial main menu I use the following lines of code:

```
midScreenX = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2;
midScreenY = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2;

    WarScene *battle = [[WarScene alloc] initWithSize: CGSizeMake(midScreenX*2, midScreenY*2)];
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition revealWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:1.0];
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    UIView *viewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:101];
    [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
    [skView presentScene:battle transition:reveal];
```

This works... I think. I open up a new scene, my second scene is the correct size and at least fills the screen. There is a node in that scene which is too big for the screen, and I am working on changing that, but I don't think that that would actually effect the UIScreen's bounds.

The problem arises when I return to the main menu with the following code:

```
midScreenX = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2;
midScreenY = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2;

GameScene *map = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize: CGSizeMake(midScreenX*2 ,midScreenY*2)];
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition revealWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:1.0];
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
UIView *viewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:3];
[viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
[skView presentScene:map transition:reveal];
```

As far as I can work out, the values being passed through should be exactly the same as the values initially sent for [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size and yet the scene which is initialised is far too big.

Is there anything that I could be doing which might affect [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size? Or have I misunderstood what init and .bounds actually do?

In terms of what I have already done to try and solve this problem myself, I have looked at examples of how scenes are normally initialised. I see that often values are used in place of .bounds for example :

```
initWithSize: CGSizeMake(1024,768)
```

However, wouldn't that mean that on different devices the scene wouldn't be shown properly/fully?

Comment: `InitWithSize:CGSize([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);` ? `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width` returns the width of your device width in points (not pixels), so if screenWidth is 320 points, on iPhone 3GS it is 320 pixels but on iPhone 4, it's 640 pixels (just answering your question title) :D

Comment: @Jack Schofield which orientation u use?

Comment: Landscape, although I have tried switching height and width to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using iOS 6 or iOS 7, 
both [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width and [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height is same in all orientation.. 
but in iOS 8 it give one value in landscape and give another value in portrait mode

```
NSLog(@"width %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);  //portrait ios7 or 6 = 320  , landscape ios7 or 6 = 320
NSLog(@"height %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height); //portrait ios7 or 6 = 568 ,  landscape ios7 or 6 = 568

NSLog(@"width %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);  //portrait ios8 = 320  , landscape ios8 = 568
NSLog(@"height %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height); //portrait ios8 = 568 ,  landscape ios8 = 320
```

so we can check conditions like this,

```
CGFloat midScreenX,midScreenY;
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape((UIDeviceOrientation)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]))
{
    //landscape mode
    midScreenX = ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width>[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height?[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height)/2;
    midScreenY = ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width<[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height?[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height)/2;
}
else
{
    //portrait mode
    midScreenX = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width/2;
    midScreenY = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height/2;
}
```

I hope you warScene and gameScene are subclass of SKScene. The method initWithSize returns, A newly initialized scene object. and parameter 'size' is The size of the scene in points.

For more information refer https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/initWithSize:

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used your code and it didn't solve the problem.

I've checked and my width is 667 throughout the code and my height is 375 throughout. However, my very first scene initialises itself differently from when the app opens into the menu and when the menu just creates itself. All scenes are subclasses of SKScene. Is there any other way of initialising it than initWithSize?